# HTML table inside DIV does not align text correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align text in a table cell to be right aligned but for some reason, I am not able to get this working.

here is what my code looks like

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
    <table>
         <tr>
             <td>15</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>20</td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Why is this not aligning the text to the right?

Note I don't have the option to use a separate CSS it has to be "inline" as per above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your table with a row of longer text. You will see that the text is all right aligned, but the table is not full width.

```html
<div style="text-align: right;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Something longer</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is a correction to make the table full width.

```html
    <div style="text-align: right;">
      <table width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Something longer</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

`width="100%"` is inline, but not CSS. If you want it CSS then do this:

```html
        <div style="text-align: right;">
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <td>15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Something longer</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
```